# Need Comma seperated output for N number of values in Shell

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, scripting-language

Given below is a script with X number of Outputs:

```
#!/bin/bash

instant_client="/root/ora_client/instantclient_11_2"
output=`$instant_client/sqlplus -s HRUSER/HRUSER@TOMLWF <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set lines 10000
set pagesize 10000
select count (1) from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and     o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);

EOF

exit`

echo $output

Output:
cand1
cand2
cand3
cand62
```

Required Output:

```
cand1, cand2, cand3, cand62
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. What is your question?

Comment: when i try to run the above script, i get the following output as follows: cand1 cand2 cand3 cand62. But i need the output as comma separated as cand1, cand2, cand3, cand62

Comment: Anyone out there ???? Please Help A.S.A.P

Comment: Are you ever going to solve this problem? This is at least the 3rd question related to the same query. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure `echo $output` produces many lines of output ?

Comment: @shellter: Hopefully i will be solving this problem, I have to , as i have no other choice. The reason that i am facing the problem is because i will have to include this script in our product which is integrated with shell node. Thanks for the Encouraging words.

Comment: @jfgagne: yes ur correct. it will just give the count.

Comment: @jfgagne: Actually i the query should have been ....select o.candidateid from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require spaces:

```
... | paste -d, -s -
```

If you need spaces:

```
... | paste -d, -s - | sed 's/,/, /g'
```

Comment: it is not helping me .... it is giving the same output ......echo $output |  paste -d, -s -

Comment: Guys the below query worked for me ... i used listagg function ..... select listagg(o.candidateid, ',') within group (order by joiningdate, o.candidateid) from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);

Answer (score 0):

Use awk and and change the ORS:

```
echo $output | awk -v ORS=", "  '{print $0}'
```

Comment: This can be simplified: `awk 1 ORS=", "`

Comment: Guys the below query worked for me ... i used listagg function ..... select listagg(o.candidateid, ',') within group (order by joiningdate, o.candidateid) from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);